# Thermistor probes wired in parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, thermistor

I have three temperature probes. 
Each probe consists of four sensors (NTC) with a common wire.
The sensors wires are connected together and the common wire for each probe is available:

[image: Connections diagram]

The wiring can not be modified, it is used on a storage silo for cereals, each sensor on a probe is fixed at a specific depth.
If I try to measure for example NTC11, the equivalent circuit will be:

[image: Equivalent circuit]

and the measured value is corrupted by the other resistances in parallel with NTC11.

How can I measure NTC11 without caring about the other values in the system ?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to take values for all possible permutations, then solve the matrix of results for the individual values.

Comment: So it is simply a math problem. 12 equations with 12 variables to determine. Thank you for your insight, @Janka.

Comment: Some say such solutions are genius. I think they are crap because they use math as a delibrate obfuscation tool. The only reason I can think of doing such a thing is selling an overpriced tailored "data logger" which de-obfuscates the data.

Comment: Yes, indeed, they are selling a dedicated reading tool like this one: https://www.ventisec.pt/produtos/monitorizacao-da-temperatura/sistema-automatico     Can this question be marked as "answered" ?

Comment: I'll bet they only power one of the thermistors at one time, by taking comm1 and comm2 to high impedance and only applying voltage on sensor 1 line you could sense one thermistor at a time. See if they have any analog muxes on their PCB

Comment: @Voltage Spike: the equivalent schematic assumes that all the external elements are high impedance. Even if you measure between Sensor 1 line and COMM1 with COMM2 and COMM3 being left floating, you get other parallel resistances across NTC11.

Comment: @Rowland You need an excitation voltage to measure resistance of an NTC, where is this being applied?

Comment: @Voltage Spike: I was considering to build a voltage divider, COMM1 tied to GND and Sensor 1 line connected to a voltage source through a resistor. The voltage at Sensor 1 line can be measured using an ADC.